# HDD test Airflow Current Temperature

Tags: hard-drive, temperature

I'm interested in buying a new HDD.
The seller sent me these results for a 160GB 2.5 5400rpm SATA hard drive (WD1600BEVS)

So, could you help me interpret these values?
Looks like the threshold was never violated, but the "Current" value is what bugs me...
And the graphic data seems ok, too.

The results are these:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Threshold (40) was violated at some point in the past when the current dropped to 37 (which I believe implies 63C), and became the `Worst`. At present your disk appears to be at 72 (which I believe implies 28C).

Current is always changing. If the `Current` value falls below `Worst`, then `Worst` will be replaced with `Current's` current value.

Perhaps its that the value is counting down that is the cause for your confusion. Most smart stats establish a high value (usually 255 or 100) and count down from it. When they drop to or below `Threshold`, then the stat is considered to be in a failed state. I am surmising based on the info provided that the AirFlow Temp stat is based on

```
Initial:   100 => 100      = 0C 
Current:   72  => 100 - 72 = 28C
Threshold: 40  => 100 - 40 = 60C 
Worst:     37  => 100 - 37 = 63C
```

63C is just about max temp for most HDDs.

Comment: Now I get it! Those are the inverted values.
Thank you so much.
So, about buying it, what do you think?
Will the disk last long? I know it's from 2007

Comment: its always a safe bet to assume that a disk will last at least a little longer than its manufacturer warrenty period, and to closely monitor its health. And evaluate your backup plan. Its always best to have a plan in case of catorstrophic failure.